# Problem using cmake QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, windows, compile

I'm trying to compile QGIS 3.0 on Windows. I want to port it to Windows RT (Windows on Arm)

I keep getting this error:

```
Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib - not found
CMake Error at cmake/FindSpatiaLite.cmake:75 (MESSAGE):
  Found SpatiaLite, but version is too old.  Requires at least version 4.2.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:251 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

How do I fix this? I have tried setting up OSGeo4W with spatialite 4.3, but it still thinks that my version is too old.

I have been following the install guide in the source code [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL)

**EDIT 1:** According to CMAKE I get two errors: https://hastebin.com/woherijadi.tex